# Vue JS - Video processing with v-for play/pause

Tags: javascript, vue.js, video, vuejs2

I accept links to videos using requests then using v-for I display them the problem is that the play button only works for one video, and not for all, I want play to work for each video also pause here is my code

```
<video
  width="206"
  height="126"
  :src="c.video"
  @playing="updatePaused"
  @pause="updatePaused"
  @canplay="updatePaused"
></video>

  <span v-show="paused" @click="play" class="play_btn1"
    ><i class="uil uil-play"></i
  ></span>
  <span
    v-show="playing"
    @click="pause"
    class="play_btn1"
    ><i class="uil uil-pause"></i
  ></span>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    playing() {
      return !this.paused;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updatePaused(e) {
      this.videoElement = e.target;
      this.paused = e.target.paused;
    },
    play() {
      this.videoElement.play();
    },
    pause() {
      this.videoElement.pause();
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      videoElement: null,

    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Where is the 'v-for'? Is the code you posted the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ref to access an HTML element. Just bind ref with whatever name inside the loop and you can access the element using `this.$refs[<name>]`.

Now since ref is inside a loop you gonna have to access it using `this.$refs[<name>][<loopIndex>]`.

Learn more about refs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      videosState: {},
      videos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          url:
            "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          url:
            "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_10mb.mp4"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeVideoState(idx) {
      // Create initial state for the video if it
      // it doesn't exist
      if (!this.videosState[idx]) {
        /**
          When you add a new field to
          an object that doesn't exist 
          yet(in the object), vue doesn't 
          know about the changes. So `this.$set`
          notifies vue about the change
          so that vue can update the
          dom correctly.
        */
        this.$set(this.videosState, idx, {
          play: false
        })
      }

      const isPlaying = this.videosState[idx].play;
      const video = this.$refs.video[idx];

      if (!isPlaying) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        video.pause();
      }

      this.videosState[idx].play = !isPlaying
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="(video, idx) in videos"
    :key="video.id"
    style="
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    "
  >
    <video ref="video" :src="video.url" width="400"></video>
    <button @click="changeVideoState(idx)">
      {{ videosState[idx] && videosState[idx].play ? "Pause" : "Play" }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

**Note:** If you want to access refs when component is loaded/created you gonna have to do it in `mounted` lifecycle:

```
new Vue({
    mounted() {
        // Access refs here
    }
})
```

Refs are only available after the component is fully rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how to make it so that initially there was one button, Play changed to Pause when you click on Play

Comment: You need to track each video's state. See the updated answer. All of the videos state are tracked in `videosState` object.